# Using arrays in XSLT 1.0 to build a table with uneven number of rows

Tags: html, arrays, xslt

I have an XML structure such as the following:

```
<people>
    <attending>
        <person><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Doe</lastname></person>
        <person><firstname>George</firstname><lastname>Washington</lastname></person>
        <person><firstname>Henry</firstname><lastname>Dodson</lastname></person>
    </attending>
    <maybe>
        <person><firstname>Jackie</firstname><lastname>Gleason</lastname></person>
        <person><firstname>Jill</firstname><lastname>Hill</lastname></person>
    </maybe>
</people>
```

I want to build a single HTML table using XSLT 1.0 with the information in both `attending` and `maybe` elements, but they are never guaranteed to have the same amount of elements. I'd like the table to look like this (or similar):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Attending</th><th>Maybe</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td><td>Jackie Gleason</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>George Washington</td><td>Jill Hill</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Henry Dodson</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So since I can only do an `xsl:for-each` over one element at a time, I could build two separate tables (one column at a time), and put each table in two cells side-by-side of a larger, encompassing table. But, **I need one table**. (If you'd like to know why, it's for cross-browser styling reasons, and tables within tables become difficult to control cross browser. One table would alleviate a lot of this.)

The next obvious thing would be to build two arrays, one with the `attending` node-set and one with the `maybe` node-set, then do an index based `xsl:for-each` where I look up the index in each array, because of course HTML tables need to be built one row at a time, but unfortunately my data is stored as columns. Also, the XSLT doesn't know beforehand how many of each `attending` or `maybe` there will be, so it has to be able to dynamically handle it.

- Does XSLT 1.0 support such arrays?
- How do I do a `xsl:for-each` iteration over such arrays? (As in `$attending[index]` where `index` is my "for each" counter)

I would prefer answers for XSLT 1.0 since that is the framework I am constrained to, but I am open to hearing about how this could be done in later versions of XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/people">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Attending</th>
            <th>Maybe</th>
        </tr>       
        <xsl:call-template name="rows"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="rows">
    <xsl:param name="i" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="*/person[$i]">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="attending/person[$i]"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="maybe/person[$i]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="rows">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="person">
    <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I like this templating approach. These appear to be the "function" equivalent of XSLT. Clearly I have a lot to learn. I will play around to try to find out the answer to my next question: Is there a way to achieve similar functionality if the element origins for the two different "columns" are not the same? Say `attending` was in XML path `/people/invited/responded` and `maybe` was in XML path `/people/invited`?

Comment: The XSLT language is Turing-complete, so there's always a way (usually more than one).

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. The key to achieving what I asked in my follow up comment is to (1) alter the `xsl:if test` attribute and (2) change what is selected in the `xsl:apply-templates select` attribute. In the case of my first follow up comment, the answer would be to make (1) `xsl:if test="((invited/responded/attending[$i]/person) or (/people/invited/responded/person[$i]))` and (2) make the first `xsl:apply-templates select="invited/responded/attending[$i]/person` and the second `xsl:apply-templates select="invited/maybe/person[$i]`.

Comment: (The above comment assumes that the XML structure in my primary example is different such that 1. there is 1 `person` element per `attending` element, and 2. there are multiple `person` elements in the `maybe` element. This is what I was facing in my real world application. Thanks again @michael.hor257k for pointing me in the right direction.)